# How do I tell if an atom contains a sub atom in Prolog

Tags: split, prolog, contains

I am deigning a program which takes in an argument (an atom). Then splits it up into its parts as defined with the program, for instance, I would like

```
func(argv) :-
    atom_split(argv,'else:',Commands),
    atom_split(argv,'+',Commands),
    atom_split(argv,'==',Commands),
    atom_split(argv,'>',Commands),
    atom_split(argv,'<',Commands),
    atom_split(argv,'!=',Commands),
```

to split the atom into its basic parts, preferably in a queue order for parsing later.  Furthermore, not all of the parts will necessarily be a part of the input atom, adding to its complexity.  Ideally, in the end, I would have a stack with the individual parts of the split atom, for instance

```
func('A+B==C').
func(argv) :-
    atom_split(argv,'else:',Commands),
    atom_split(argv,'+',Commands),
    atom_split(argv,'==',Commands),
    atom_split(argv,'>',Commands),
    atom_split(argv,'<',Commands),
    atom_split(argv,'!=',Commands),

Commands = [A,+,B,==,C].
```

I will then use these commands to tell if something fits in a grammar:

```
?- func(‘E+d;’). 
true. 
?-func(‘if:a and b’). 
false.
```

Comment: Please note that `atom_split/3` is specific to some implementations - and not fully defined. The ISO standard provides under [8.16](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#8.16): `sub_atom/5`, `atom_concat/2`.

Answer (score 3):

The easy answer: use [`sub_atom/5`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=sub_atom/5). It should be available in every Prolog implementation.

But your approach is very questionable. Are you certain that your expressions must be atoms? From the Prolog top level (the interpreter), you can already get for free the parsing of most of the expressions you show in the question. For example:

```
?- Expr = (a + b == c), write_canonical(Expr).
==(+(a,b),c)
Expr =  (a+b==c).
```

In this example, each of `=`, `+`, and `==` are already defined as Prolog operators, so something like `a + b == c` is actually a valid Prolog term.
You can of course [define your own operators](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=operators).

The other option would be to write a proper "parser" for the expressions, which is not too difficult in Prolog. You can probably start off by making your expression to be a [list of chars or a list of codes](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=chars). Then, what you seem to be after is a tokenizer, probably easiest to implement in the more convenient [DCG notation](http://www.metalevel.at/dcg.html). I think it should be possible to find code examples for doing this, and your question as it is at the moment does not provide enough information to try and show actual code for doing the tokenization or parsing.

Comment: I see what you are saying, however, I am using BNF to determine if a given syntax is correct, so, I need to be able to break everything down into a basic form I believe. I need to be able to say something like `?- func(‘E+d;’). true. ?-func(‘if:a and b’). false.`